# Nodes always null even if they exist

Tags: html, xpath, visual-studio-2015, html-agility-pack

I'm working on a little project to extract table data from HTML files which are on my computer and then I'll put them in an Excel table. I'll use this data to save into database. The only part I'm stuck on is HTML parsing right now. My code is below. I got the XPath from Firefox's Firebug extension. I uploaded the complete HTML file to Dropbox if you want to look at it.

[Download File Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ogoqm2sf1g1l71v/sample.HTML?dl=0)

```
OpenFileDialog dosyaSec = new OpenFileDialog();
dosyaSec.FileName = "*.HTML";
if (dosyaSec.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument myHtml = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    myHtml.LoadHtml(dosyaSec.FileName);

    HtmlNode table = myHtml.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[6]"); //table returns null here
    if (table != null)
    {
        foreach (var cell in table.SelectNodes(".//tr//td/"))
        {
            //will deal with this later
        }
    }

}
```

And the partial HTML code is like below:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>
   ToPs 100 - SET-UP SCHEDULE /
   L3020 -
   1 /
   4MM_ST52_52315_120
</title>
<meta name="author" content="User" />
<meta name="keywords" content="L3020,
TYPE:1, Trumpf" />
</head>
<!--body bgcolor="#D0D0D0"-->
<body link="#0000ff" vlink="#800080">
<basefont face="Arial" size="1" />



<table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td colspan="4" align="left">
         <!--Ueberschrift Einzelteilinformationen-->
         <font size="4"><b>INFORMATION ON SINGLE PART&nbsp;</b></font>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td valign="top"><font size="2"><b>PART NUMBER:&nbsp;</b></font></td>
      <td valign="top"><font size="2"><b>DRAWING NUMBER:&nbsp;</b></font></td>
      <td valign="top"><font size="2"><b>GEOFILE NAME:&nbsp;</b></font></td>
      <td valign="top"><font size="2"><b>NUMBER:&nbsp;</b></font></td>
   </tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">3&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">NOID_3&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">F:\LAZER KESÝM\BMC AÞ\53 RS\53203\53203156\53203156-1-4MM.GEO&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">34&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">5&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">NOID_5&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">F:\LAZER KESÝM\BMC AÞ\53 RS\53203\53203156\53203156-3-4MM.GEO&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">42&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">2&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">NOID_2&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">F:\LAZER KESÝM\HENDRICKSON\HS508447-48\HS508453-4MM.GEO&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">1&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">1&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">NOID_1&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">F:\LAZER KESÝM\EGE ENDÜSTRÝ\10055006\10055003-4MM.GEO&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">46&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">4&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">NOID_4&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">F:\LAZER KESÝM\BMC AÞ\53 RS\53203\53203156\53203156-2-4MM.GEO&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">67&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">10&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">NOID_10&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">F:\LAZER KESÝM\BMC AÞ\57 RS\57311\57311071\57311344-4MM.GEO&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">64&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">6&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">NOID_6&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">F:\LAZER KESÝM\BMC AÞ\51 RS\51400\51400266\51400265_4MM.GEO&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">3&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">9&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">NOID_9&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">F:\LAZER KESÝM\BMC AÞ\57 RS\57311\57311071\57311341-4MM.GEO&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">68&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">8&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">NOID_8&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">F:\LAZER KESÝM\BMC AÞ\57 RS\57311\57311071\57311340-4MM.GEO&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">64&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><font size="2">7&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">NOID_7&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">F:\LAZER KESÝM\BMC AÞ\57 RS\57311\57311071\57311091-4MM.GEO&nbsp;</font></td><td valign="top"><font size="2">61&nbsp;</font></td></tr>

<tr>
      <td colspan="4" align="left">
         <!--Tafelname mit -pfad-->
         <font size="2">
         SHEET NAME:&nbsp;
         F:\LA...ÝM\TAF DOSYALARI\4MM_ST52_52315_1200X3000.taf&nbsp;
         </font>
      </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

By the way HTML was long so I only pasted the code that belongs to the sixth table. The tables don't have `id`s.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Load` method of the `HtmlDocument` to load a file. `LoadHtml` expects a HTML string.

From: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples (emphasis mine)

## Html Agility Pack Examples

For example, here is how you would fix all hrefs in a HTML *file*:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
{
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
}
doc.Save("file.htm");
```

The project has moved to: http://html-agility-pack.net

Comment: Thank you very much! Load instead of Loadhtml really worked.